# bitwise OR operation on std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have a c++ std::array typedef'd as follows:

```
typedef std::array<uint64_t, 2>MyType;
```

If I have two instances of "MyType", and I wanted to perform bitwise "OR" on these two instances, I currently have code as follows:

```
MyType instance1 { 11, 22 };
MyType instance2 { 33, 44 };
MyType output {0, 0};
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
  output[i] |= instance1[i];
  output[i] |= instance2[i];
}
```

The results of running this are

output[0] = 43; 
  output[1] = 62;

**My question is**
Is there any other way of doing this bitwise "OR" (other than looping through the elements one-by-one?)

Comment: Define your own bitwise OR between `MyType`s (aka operator overloading)? It'll still loop through elements individually but at least you don't have to write a for-loop each time you do `output = a | b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::transform`, which then does the iterations for you, as I did here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <functional> //std::bit_or

typedef std::array<uint64_t, 2 > MyType;

int main()
{
    MyType instance1 { 11, 22 };
    MyType instance2 { 33, 44 };
    MyType output {0, 0};

    std::transform(output.begin(), output.end(), instance1.begin(), output.begin(), std::bit_or<uint64_t>());
    std::transform(output.begin(), output.end(), instance2.begin(), output.begin(), std::bit_or<uint64_t>());

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) std::cout << output[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Demonstration: http://www.cpp.sh/94cs4

Note that I find your original code to be more readable than this. I'd use `std::transform` in more complex situations only.

That said, what are you actually trying to solve?
If you look for the convenience of easy component-wise operations as one would find for example in Matlab, not to my knowledge. You could write your own container class similar to `std::vector` and `std::array` and have certain operators, like `|` in your case, to work with those.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I was trying to solve the problem of when my instances scale up to, for example 100; also, if the number of elements in my std::array is scaled up to 100.  I was looking for a way to do bulk operation instead of multiple iterations

Comment: @user6013878 In that case, I'd make them an array of arrays and use two loops.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your input